# duplicate a Database content into another database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I have a database that I want to duplicate into another database.

I'm using Sql Server 2012 Express Management Studio

I tried to make a backup of the database and tried to restore it as another database, but I couldn't

It happens that I was using LocalDB\v11.0, but I had to upgrade my sql server express to the version that accepts remote connections.

But now I have two servers, LocalDB\v11.0 and .\SQLEXPRESS, my database is in LocalDB and I want it in .\SQLEXPRESS

How can I do that?

Rafael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I haven't tried but this shouldn't be the case. AFAIK, `LocalDB\v11.0` introduced in SQL Server 2012 and you can backup/restore between localdb and sqlexpress.

if that's not working then try posting the error/issue you are getting in this post.

Anyway, you can also script your database, schema and data and then run those script locally.

See this post here for the same ...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b75bef7e-13f3-4658-8d43-9df12ab4c320/connecting-localdb-using-sql-server-management-studio-express

Once you are connected, you can view the DB objects and script them in SSMS; thereafter run those same script in your sqlexpress instance.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I don't know how it can help me. The link tells how to connect to local db using SSME and I the backup/restore is not working among localdeb and sqlexpress. I'm still ignorant of the solution.